# Pause a QThread

Tags: multithreading, qt

`UpdateThread` is-a `QThread` That sets up a `QTimer` in `UpdateThread::run()` that calls slot `UpdateThread::tick()` every `t` ms. Now based upon some condition I need to `Pause` the Thread and after *some* time based upon another condition I need to wake it up.

---

- Is the Way I am doing the `QTimer` thing is Okay ? or I should move the `tick` code to `run` and call the `QThread::start()` every `t` ms ?
- How can I Pause and wake up the threads conditionally
- Or I should just `stop()` the QTimer and `start()` it latter ?

Comment: Who needs to start/stop the timer? The GUI thread or the thread that `UpdateThread::run()` executes in?

Answer (score 3):

First of all, you shouldn't define slots on your `QThread` subclass and call them from within `run()` - the slots will be executed (by performing a cross-thread slot invocation) in the context of the thread that *owns* your `UpdateThread` instance (the same one that created it, unless you called `moveToThread()` on it), not in the context of the thread represented by `UpdateThread`. Remember this mnemonic:

> In `run()`, `QThread::thread() != this`

Instead, define the slots on a QObject subclass that you create inside `run()`.

Ok, with that out of the way, let's have a look at the timer. The [`QTimer`](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.7/qtimer.html) documentation contains the following:

> In multithreaded applications, you can use `QTimer` in any thread that has an event loop.
>   To start an event loop from a non-GUI thread, use [`QThread::exec()`](http://doc.trolltech.com/latest/qthread.html#exec). Qt uses the timer's
>   [thread affinity](http://doc.trolltech.com/latest/qobject.html#thread) to determine which thread will emit the [`timeout()`](http://doc.trolltech.com/latest/qtimer.html#timeout) signal.
>   *Because of this, you must start and stop the timer in its thread; it is not possible to
>   start a timer from another thread.*

(emphasis mine) Take particular note of the last sentence.

The solution is to do a cross-thread call of `QTimer::start()` and `QTimer::stop()`. You might know about cross-thread signal/slot connections. This uses the same underlying mechanism, which is exposed in [`QMetaObject::invokeMethod()`](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.7/qmetaobject.html#invokeMethod-3):

```
class UpdateThread : public QThread {
    Q_OBJECT
private:
    QObject * m_timer; // just a QObject* so we're not tempted
                       // to call functions on it
    QMutext m_mutex; // protects 'm_timer'
public:
    explicit UpdateThread( QObject * parent=0 )
        : QThread( parent ), m_timer( 0 ) {}
    // ...
private:
    /* reimpl */ void run() {
        QTimer timer;
        // ...'timer' setup code goes here...
        {
            const QMutexLocker locker( &m_mutex );
            m_timer = &timer; // publish 'timer' through 'm_timer'
        }
        // main code of run()
        exec(); // start event loop so we get timer's timeout()s
                // and we can receive cross-thread method calls
        {
            const QMutexLocker locker( &m_mutex );
            m_timer = 0; // un-publish before we delete `timer`
        }
    }
public Q_SLOTS:
    void startTimer() {
        const QMutexLocker locker( &m_mutex );
        if ( !m_timer ) return;
        // perform cross-thread method call:
        QMetaObject::invokeMethod( m_timer, "start", Qt::QueuedConnection );
    }
    void stopTimer() {
        const QMutexLocker locker( &m_mutex );
        if ( !m_timer ) return;
        // perform cross-thread method call:
        QMetaObject::invokeMethod( m_timer, "stop", Qt::QueuedConnection );
    }
};
```

Now, this is how you start/stop the timer from the GUI thread. But you were also asking about alternatives.

1. Move `tick()` code into `run()`, call `UpdateThread::start()` every `t` milliseconds.

   This is suboptimal, as it would create and destroy threads every `t` ms. Thread creation is still an expensive operation. Also, if `UpdateThread::run()` isn't done by the time you next call `start()`, you'll lose timer ticks.
2. `UpdateThread` as outlined above.

   This isn't too bad, but it's not idiomatic multithreading, I'd say. It's a good solution if the timer fires so often that that alone would slow down the GUI thread somehow, though you might lose timer ticks this way, too.
3. `QThreadPool`

   My favourite. Move the code that performs `tick()` into an implementation of `QRunnable::run()`, and queue a new runnable on a thread pool whenever the timer fires. In this case, the timer would most naturally live in the GUI thread, avoiding the need for cross-thead method calls as outlined above. Unless the GUI thread itself is overloaded, you won't miss any timer ticks. You also get for free scaling to the number of cores in the system (if you don't want that, don't use `QThreadPool::globalInstance()` but create your own instance and call `setMaxThreadCount(1)`).

Comment: Well I am making `UpdateThread` is a `QRunnable` (**not** a `QThread`). and Im moving `QTimer`s out of it.I'll make an `UpdateThreadPool` that is a `QThreadPool`. all `UpdateThread` will have a `DG::RectArea*` which is owned by another thread. and the `UpdateThread::run()`s will report to it. and I think I should turn `autoDelete` off. as I've fixed 16 `RectArea`s and for them 16 fixed `UpdateThread`s. and keep the ownership of `UpdateThread` to the main thread. and `RectArea` is not a `QObject`. Is it Okay ? or something is wrong there already ? and Where should I put the `Timer` thing Here ?